# Compare int and unsigned int

Tags: c, gcc

If one needs to compare `int x` with `unsigned int y` which is safer/better/nicer in `C99` and with `gcc 4.4+`:

1. `(unsigned int)x == y`
2. `x == (int)y`

Does it matter?

Comment: It usually don't matter much, except in overflow situations (>= MAX_UINT/2, ie MAX_INT, ie 2**31 on 32 bits machines).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: But this is about 50% of the possible values! What could matter more?

Comment: I agree, but with overflows the test don't really have natural sense... (and the test is still the same inside the machine). So it still don't matter... machine code is about the same...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Safest is to check that the number is in range before casting:

```
if (x >= 0 && ((unsigned int)x) == y)
```

Comment: Thanks, and is it OK to do `(int)y` when we're sure that `y < INT_MAX/2`?

Comment: Yes, it is ok, and probably faster to type (and to execute, when the compiler is not very optimizing)

Comment: You shouldn't do the cast and let the compiler chose. The rules for "usual arithmetic conversions" are a bit complicated but in essence there are architectures where the conversion would be to `int` and others where the conversion would be to `unsigned`, and for good reasons.

Comment: @James, you probably mean `y < INT_MAX`, no?

Comment: @Jens: Yes, I did, `y < INT_MAX`.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Are there? As I understand 6.3.3.1, `int` and `unsigned` have the same conversion rank, and per 6.3.1.8 ("Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.") the `int` should always be converted to `unsigned`. No?

Comment: undur_gongor is correct, which means that (as long as `x` is an `int`) the cast is unnecessary: `if (x >= 0 && x == y)` is fine.

Comment: What I'm doing is casting the unsigned int to a long, and then the compiler will cast the int implicitly to a long too.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it does matter.

On a platform with 32bit `int` with e.g.

```
int x = -1;
unsigned y = 0xffffffff;
```

the expression `x == y` would yield `1` because through the "usual arithmetic conversions" the value of `x` is converted to `unsigned` and thus to `0xffffffff`.

The expression `(unsigned int)x == y` is `1` as well. The only difference is that you do the conversion explicitly with a cast.

The expression `x == (int)y` will most likely be `1` as well because converting `0xffffffff` to `int` yields `-1` on most platforms (two's complement negatives). Strictly speaking this is implementation-defined behavior and thus might vary on different platforms.

Note that in none of the cases you will get the "expected" result `0`. A good implementation is given in [Mark Byers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8233184/908515).