# Comparison between unsigned int and int without using cast operator

Tags: c, int, compare, type-conversion, unsigned-integer

Everyone I looked around there exists a topic about my question yet I could not find.

```
unsigned int x = 5; 
int y = -3;
if(y<x)
   func1();
else
   func2();
```

`func2` is called . But I want `func1` called.

I know that I must use a cast operator when comparing these values.
But it is not allowed to use the cast operator or changing the type of a variable.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8233184/4185106

Comment: If conversions warnings are enabled, the compiler should always generate one on such comparisons without explicit cast. Even if you check (y < 0) before the compare. So you will not get along without cast (and you should not!). That is actually how a cast should only be used: with full understanding about the problems. A coding style for C which _completely_ forbids typecasts but does not enforcing signed-ness warnings (and most/all other warnings) goes much too far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check if `y` is a negative value, then knowing that, you know that `x` will always be bigger since it is unsigned.

If `y` is not negative, then compare its value directly to `x`. I do not think this will cause an issue since there is no negative sign present.

See the below example:

```
if(y<0)
{
    //x>y
    func1();
}
else if (y<x)
{
    //lets say y=3, and x=5
    func1();
}
else
{
    func2();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write the condition in the if statement the following way

```
if( y < 0 || y<x)
   func1();
else
   func2();
```

Comment: That would still generate a warning for the comparison. Sadly enough, coding styles disallow casts completely, but do not enforce warnings. Casts sometimes _do_ make sense sometimes. This example is actually a perfect proof.

Answer (score 0):

Use wider integer math for the compare.  No cast used, type of variables are not changed.
An optimized compiler will not do a multiplication, just a integer widening.
Could use a `* 1LL` or `+ 0LL` instead

```
int main(void) {
  long long ll = 1;
  unsigned int x = 5;
  int y = -3;
  // if (y < x)
  if (ll * y < ll * x)
    puts("func1();");
  else
    puts("func2();");
  return 0;
}

Output: func1();
```

`long long` is usually wider than `int`: See [How to determine integer types that are twice the width as `int` and `unsigned`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25982992/2410359)

Answer (score -1):

Try complementing `y` (`~y`), it becomes 2

```
unsigned int x = 5; 
int y = -3;
if(~y<x)
   func1();
else
   func2();
```

Comment: Thank you ,
By using this notation ~y , will we take first complement of variable y ?

Comment: @user3151801 It is a wrong condition. Consider the case when y is equal to -3 and x is equal to 2.

Comment: well then you can add INT_MAX to both of them and compare. #include <limits.h>

Comment: That is _implementation defined behaviour_, as it relies on 2's complement representation. It even does not work for `y == INT_MIN` Also what if `x >= -(llong long)(INT_MIN)` (presumed `long long` has more bits than `int`)?